# Regarding WordPress custom homepage

Tags: wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This is more of a process question than coding. I have a custom homepage with logo, menu, footer similar to other pages. But there are few other contents which are different in the homepage, as usual, i.e, a title, a description div, a social links div and a few more, which are only in the home page.

Now the question is, since I want the admin to change this dynamically, how should I easily implement this for the site owner. Should I make a top-level menu named Homepage in WordPress dashboard and add all these meta boxes (with title, description, social fields) on that admin page so that he can fill this in from the back-end or make a custom post-type with the mentioned custom fields? Or should I add a menu under appearance with the relevant fields to be filled.

I am confused about the standard way. I am new to WordPress and just learning. This clarification will help me get a pre-idea. I completed the HTML and now converting the site to WordPress. Just give me a general overview please, nothing detail, I'll get the rest done. I would like to know the difference between the options mentioned above in a nut-shell (what is for what actually) and what is the standard way to add the custom home page fields for the site admin to input page contents easily.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a static front page.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Basically you can create a standard page and then from wordpress customizer make that page a front page. Client will edit it from the back end just as any other standard page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am developing a theme actually. So I cannot create a static homepage as anybody can be my client. I decided to add custom post types for additional information.